# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'path' & 'title'

Tags: php

I moved the site to a new hosting (PHP 5.6), and after this I'm getting this error:

> PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'path' in /home/sitedirectory/public_html/website/templates/all_files.php on line 4

Here is that file

---

```
<?php defined('DIR') OR exit ?>
        <div class="atachment"><?php echo (l()=='ge') ? 'Attached Documents' : 'Attachments'; ?></div>
<?php foreach($files as $file) : ?>        
        <div class="pdf"><a href="<?php echo $file['path'];?>"><?php echo $file['title'];?></a></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Where is `$files` being defined?

Comment: What does `$files` contain?

Comment: By not trying to use a string value as if it was an array …

Comment: Have you tried debugging? e.g. print_r($files);

Comment: I don't know.... I'll search for it then....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means the `$file` array does not contain the key `path` (or `title`);

Do some debugging in your code to find the reason for the error. E.g., add:

```
print_r( $file );
```

And see if it outputs an array with these keys.

It could be that some `$files` are empty by nature, in which case, do:

```
<?php foreach($files as $file) : ?>   
    <?php if ( isset( $file['path'] ) && isset( $file['title'] ) ) : ?>     
        <div class="pdf"><a href="<?php echo $file['path'];?>"><?php echo $file['title'];?></a></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thank You @Niraj Shah

It worked, the code fixed the Problem :)